# How to track app install from snapchat ads

Tags: react-native, ads, snapchat

We are starting an ad campaign on snapchat but can't seem to find any documentation to track user acquisition.

I know there is snapchat pixel for website but haven't found anything for react native.

How do one track app install from a snapchat app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [appsflyer](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/211011983-Snapchat-setup-guide) does it for you.